# Use Service in angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I use in service in my angular app as follows:

```
app.service('sharedProperties', function () {
    var property;

    return {
        getProperty: function () {
            return property;
        },
        setProperty: function(value) {
            property = value;
        }
    };
});

    $scope.Somefunc= function(Mname) 
    {
        $http.post("SomeServlet",{
            "name": Mname,
        }).then(function(response) {

            sharedProperties.setProperty(response.data);
            window.location = "/blabla/page2.html";

        });
    };
```

And in page2 (another conroller) i get the value:

```
app.controller('controller2', function($scope,$http,sharedProperties) {

        $scope.UserProperties = sharedProperties.getProperty();
});
```

and its doesnt work, always i get undefined.

Comment: once you use `window.location` which will reload your page.and intialize all of your angular component again..which will turns out service in its initial state

Answer (score 0):

In order for it to work, you must set the angular routing function which will take care of moving to another page without refreshing your current page (also called SPA - Single Page Application).

Take a look [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route), at the example in the end of the page there are the different pages and files in the mini system.

I remind you that angular is meant to work with single page applications, so if you refresh the page and change it into another one - You sort of lose the point of using it.